# Not able to link Mersenne twister inside Freeswitch module

Tags: c, gcc, freeswitch

I am trying to add Mersenne twister random library inside a Freeswitch module but when I try to compile and link I get:

```
making all mod_svbilling
Compiling /usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/mod_svbilling.c...
Compiling /usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/mod_svbilling.c ...
Creating mod_svbilling.so...
mtwist.o: In function `mts_lrand':
mtwist.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `mts_lrand'
.libs/mod_svbilling.o:/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/./mtwist/mtwist.h:417: first defined here
mtwist.o: In function `mts_llrand':
mtwist.c:(.text+0x6d): multiple definition of `mts_llrand'
.libs/mod_svbilling.o:/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/./mtwist/mtwist.h:446: first defined here
mtwist.o: In function `mts_drand':
mtwist.c:(.text+0x189): multiple definition of `mts_drand'
.libs/mod_svbilling.o:/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/./mtwist/mtwist.h:488: first defined here
mtwist.o: In function `mts_ldrand':
mtwist.c:(.text+0x210): multiple definition of `mts_ldrand'
.libs/mod_svbilling.o:/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/./mtwist/mtwist.h:507: first defined here
mtwist.o: In function `mt_lrand':
mtwist.c:(.text+0x349): multiple definition of `mt_lrand'
.libs/mod_svbilling.o:/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/./mtwist/mtwist.h:555: first defined here
mtwist.o: In function `mt_llrand':
mtwist.c:(.text+0x3d7): multiple definition of `mt_llrand'
.libs/mod_svbilling.o:/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/./mtwist/mtwist.h:575: first defined here
mtwist.o: In function `mt_drand':
mtwist.c:(.text+0x55c): multiple definition of `mt_drand'
.libs/mod_svbilling.o:/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/./mtwist/mtwist.h:618: first defined here
mtwist.o: In function `mt_ldrand':
mtwist.c:(.text+0x604): multiple definition of `mt_ldrand'
.libs/mod_svbilling.o:/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/mod/applications/mod_svbilling/./mtwist/mtwist.h:636: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gcc -I. -I./svblic -I./mtwist -fPIC -DVERSION= -DSVN_REV=108M -I/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/libs/curl/include -I/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/include -I/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/src/include -I/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/libs/libteletone/src -I/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/libs/stfu -fPIC -Werror -fvisibility=hidden -DSWITCH_API_VISIBILITY=1 -DHAVE_VISIBILITY=1 -g -ggdb -DHAVE_OPENSSL -g -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -Wdeclaration-after-statement -D_GNU_SOURCE -shared -o .libs/mod_svbilling.so -shared -Wl,-x .libs/mod_svbilling.o aes.o lic.o md5.o sysinfo.o mtwist.o  -lsqlite3 -lm /usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/.libs/libfreeswitch.so -L/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib -lpq /usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib/.libs/libexpat.a /usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/libs/apr/.libs/libapr-1.a -lpthread -L/usr/src/freeswitch-1.2.12/libs/srtp -lcrypt -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz -lncurses -ljpeg -lodbc   -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/freeswitch/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/freeswitch/mod
make[4]: *** [mod_svbilling.so] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all] Error 1
make[2]: *** [mod_svbilling-all] Error 1
make[1]: *** [mod_svbilling] Error 2
make: *** [mod_svbilling] Error 2
```

Makefile I am using looks like:

```
BASE=../../../..
SVN_REV=$(shell svnversion -n .)
SVB_LIB_FLAGS = -lm -lpthread -lsqlite3
SVB_CFLAGS = -I. -I./svblic -I./mtwist -fPIC
MOD_CFLAGS=$(SVB_LIB_FLAGS) $(SVB_CFLAGS) -DVERSION=$(VERSION) -DSVN_REV=$(SVN_REV)
LOCAL_OBJS=aes.o lic.o md5.o sysinfo.o mtwist.o
local_depend: $(LOCAL_OBJS)

sysinfo.o: ./svblic/sysinfo.c
    gcc $(SVB_CFLAGS) -c ./svblic/sysinfo.c

aes.o: ./svblic/aes.c
    gcc $(SVB_CFLAGS) -c ./svblic/aes.c

md5.o: ./svblic/md5.c
    gcc $(SVB_CFLAGS) -c ./svblic/md5.c

lic.o: ./svblic/lic.c
    gcc $(SVB_CFLAGS) -c ./svblic/lic.c

mtwist.o: ./mtwist/mtwist.c
    gcc $(SVB_CFLAGS) -c ./mtwist/mtwist.c

include $(BASE)/build/modmake.rules
```

I only added following header to my module source code:

```
#include "./mtwist/mtwist.h"
```

I don't know why it sais those functions are already defined. mtwist.h has one define in order to avoid redefine those functions

Any idea?

Regards

Comment: Guess #1: you made a typo somewhere and included mtwist.c instead of mtwist.h; guess #2: mtwist.h (possibly because of some #ifdef) defines some convenience functions (say, mts_drand()) which are also defined in mtwist.c -- in either case, try a "hello world" that #includes mtwist.h, prints a few numbers, and is compiled by hand, so you'll know if mtwist.[ch] are to blame or not

Comment: Please fix question to use code formatting instead of quoted text formatting. Now the make file is a mess.

Comment: Doing a simple c code including the library compiles ok. If I add the same #include to my module source it generates those errors

Comment: @hyde tnx, I wanted to do it but I wasn't sure how to fix the formatting

Comment: @LooPer could it be that you compiled your file like "gcc test.c" rather than "gcc test.c mtwist.o"? I'm asking because it would explain why you can't reproduce the failure, and googling for mt_drand & friends brought up eg http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~stjones/proj/mtwist.h, which would explain the proplem (look at MT_NO_INLINE; you may be using a different implementation, but I'll bet the issue is the same) -- I get your errors if I try "clang main.c mtwist.c"

Comment: main.c is `/* MT_NO_INLINE */
#include "mtwist.h"
int main()
{
        mt_seed32new(1);
        (void)mt_drand();
        return 0;
}

` (must improve my markdown-fu, sorry)

Comment: This is a long shot, but try adding `-std=c99` to `SVB_CFLAGS`.

Comment: I finally got compile and linking using those define `#undef MT_GENERATE_CODE_IN_HEADER
#define MT_GENERATE_CODE_IN_HEADER 0`